# Using mle() in R. Error Message: attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r

I am trying to find optimal parameters for a mixed Weibull-Distribution. I want to use the Maximum-Likelihood-Method part of the stats4 Package.

My R Code:

```
library(stats4)

x=rweibull(50,0.5,10000) #random sample x consisting of 50 Weibull-distributed elements
y=rweibull(150,1.2,200000) #random sample y consisting of 150 Weibull-distributed elements

ll=x
for (i in 1:150) ll[50+i]=y[i] #matching sample x and y to sample ll (200 elements)

llf=function(p,b1,T1,b2,T2){n=200 #llf=negative loglikelihoodfunction, 5 unknown parameters
t=ll
(-sum(log(p*(b1/T1)*((t/T1)^(-(t/T1)^(b1-1)))*exp(-(t/T1)^b1)+(1-p)(b2/T2)*((t/T2)^(-(t/T2)^(b2-1)))*exp(-(t/T2)^b2))))}

est=mle(minuslogl=llf, start=list(p=0.3,b1=0.5,T1=10000,b2=1.2,T2=200000), method="L-BFGS-B", lower=c(0,0,0,0,0), upper=c(1,1,Inf,Inf,Inf)) #estimation of 5 unknown parameters
```

However, it doesn't work. I get the following error message:
Error in minuslogl(p = 0.3, b1 = 0.5, T1 = 10000, b2 = 1.2, T2 = 2e+05) : 
  attempt to apply non-function

I used traceback() to find the error, but it doesn't make it easier for me to find the mistake.

Has anyone an idea what went wrong?
Maybe it is too difficult for R to optimize 5 parameters for such a difficult Maximum-Likelihood-Function?

Comment: you're (at least) missing a `*` in `(1-p)(b2/T2)`

Comment: ... but you've got more problems. Evaluating `llf` at your starting parameters gives `-Inf`.  You'll have to take it apart and see where your overflow is happening.

Comment: Hello Ben, thanks for your quick response, I'll give my best to solve the equation.